# Is there a link between copying of arrays by assignment operator and assigning values to an already defined array directly?

Tags: c, arrays

In C language, an array cannot be copied to another array directly by assignment operator.

```
int arr1[]={1,3,2};
int arr2[]={0};

arr2=arr1;//not possible
```

Also, we cannot assign values to an array that is already defined, if I am not wrong...

```
int a[3];
a[]={1,3,2}; //this is not possible
```

In the code above, `a[]` and `{1,3,2}` act as two different arrays, and an assignment operator is used between them. So, is this following the same case mentioned at the first?

Please clarify.
Thanks.

Comment: "not allowed" is the wrong term. It is just not possible. But you don't copy an array (presuming `arr1` and `arr2` are 1D arrays), but a single element. **This** is very well possible. Please clarify your question. From a wrong prerequisite, everything can be deduced.

Comment: `memset` or `memcpy` will help you to achieve the same thing though: `memcpy(arr1, arr2, sizeof arr1/sizeof *arr1);` or something

Comment: That gave me some info. Thanks @Olaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this following the same case mentioned at the first?

No, they are different.

In the first case, what you try to do is array assignment, which is not possible in C directly.  The language grammar states an [array name to be a non-modifiable lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918196/183120), so

```
arr1 = arr2;
```

is invalid. The relevant excerpt from the C11 standard draft (§6.3.2.1):

> A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that does not have array type, ...

In the second case

```
int a[3];
a[]={1,3,2};
```

you are trying to assign the initializer list `{1, 2, 3}` to an invalid sub-expression `a[]` and hence is illegal. What is assigned to it is immaterial; `a[] = 1` is invaild too.

Comment: That gave me some clarity. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not *quite* the same.

`{1,2,3}` is an initializer list. The compiler sees it and hard-codes its values into the array. Assigning an initializer-list to an array that already has a definition (`int array[3]; array={1,2,3};`) is a syntax error (clang says `expected expression` because it's expecting a closing square bracket before an assignment operator as in `int array[]={1,2,3};`).

Assigning one array to another is impossible in your case because `array type 'int [3]' is not assignable`. I'd call it something like *logic error* (the programmer just didn't know he can't do it, but the syntax is valid).

Answer (score 0):

The other posts and comments are correct in that you cannot assign a bare array after initialization.

However, you *can* assign to a struct that contains such an array, even after initialization, using a compound literal,

```
typedef struct {
  int v[3];
} A;

A a = {{1,2,3}};   // Valid.
a = (A){{4,5,6}};  // Also valid.
```